# An infinite list of irrational numbers from one irrational number.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There is an interesting irrational number, in binary it is,

.01101110010111011110001001101010111100110111101111...

It is made by appending the numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 etc one after the other in binary.

0,1,10,11,100,101,110,111,1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110,1111 etc

We can form a square matrix from this irrational number.

The first twenty-five binary digits would be placed in this order.

$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 4 & 9 & 16 & 25 \\
        2 & 3 & 8 & 15 & 24 \\
        5 & 6 & 7 & 14 & 23 \\
        10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 22 \\
        17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 \\
        \end{matrix}
$

So our matrix would begin with

$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 &1 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$

And the matrix would have an infinite number of digits to the right and bottom.

We can convert our matrix to a list like this.

```
    0.00010...  
    0.11000... 
    0.11111... 
    0.10110... 
    0.11100...
       ...
```

We will have a fixed, infinite eternal object. It will contain an infinite number of irrational numbers.

My question is, will this list contain numbers like the binary version of $\pi-3 = 0.141159 \ldots = 0.001001000011111100111110 \ldots$, and more important, will it contain any rational numbers like $ 0.10101010 \dots$

Comment: Notably, your list must miss *most* irrational numbers since your list is countable but the irrational numbers are uncountable.

Comment: What have you tried, in terms of answering your two questions? Seems like a simple thing to try is to extend the numbers much further to the right to see if any patterns appear. If patterns appear that suggest a rational number you could prove/disprove whether the numbers are really rational. The third number in your list is a good candidate, even though it just has 5 digits.

Comment: The first "interesting irrational number" in the question is half the base-2 [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) $C_2$.

Comment: If the list contained $\pi-3$, that would imply a remarkably fast algorithm for computing binary digits of $\pi$ -- faster than I think anybody expects exists.

Comment: @Henning Makholm Thank you for identifying the constant. I was wondering if the binary DVD version of "Gone With The Wind" would appear somewhere in the binary expansion of $\pi$. Even though the digits appear to be random, there could be some sequences that just do not appear in $\pi$, But every finite sequence of digits will appear in the Champernowne constant.

Comment: @IvanHieno: This is usually referred to the question of whether $\pi$ is _normal_ in base 2, which is unknown but strongly expected. If $\pi$ is normal, then as a consequence everything including _Gone With the Wind_ would appear in it.

Comment: @Χpẘ I don't think that there can be a pattern. If you test the $C_2$ for randomness, you will find that it is as random as a coin toss. Try it at https://nrich.maths.org/6078 use 1=heads & 0=tails. So if you pull digits in an arithmetic pattern (1,3,5,7,9...) and the digits in $C_2$ are formed from an exponential pattern, then you will always be out of sync. And your result will be random.

Comment: @Ivan FWIW $C_2$ digits are formed from a super-exponential pattern, something like $x\cdot 2^x$. In my non-answer below I mention that mapping from an index into the digits of $C_2/2$ to the size of the constituent integer involves Lambert W function.

Comment: @HenningMakholm : What if it could be shown non-constructively that $\pi-3$ is in there somewhere but there's no way to tell which row it's in? That wouldn't be a fast algorithm for digits of $\pi. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: It would still mean that a fast algorithm for digits of $\pi$ _exists_; we just wouldn't know which algorithm that is.

Answer (score 0):

NOT AT ANSWER - a long comment

Call the irrational number first mentioned in the OP, $B$. To generate digits of the numbers in the list, digits at specified indices must be selected from $B$. To calculate digit $n$ from $B$ it is first necessary to know the index of the first digit of the number in $B$ that has the same number of digits that $n$ points to. Let $f(n)$ be that index. Let $d(n)$ be the number of digits of the numbers that start at $f(n)$.

For example, take $n=500$. $f(500)=322$ and $d(500)= 7$. This means 500 indexes into the 7 digit numbers, which start at index 322. 500 corresponds to the $\lfloor\frac{500-322}7\rfloor=25$th (zero based) 7 digit number. That number is 64+25=89=1011001b. And the bit is the 3rd bit to the right of the MSB (most significant bit), namely a 1.

This formula gives the starting index for $d$ digit numbers within $B$: $s(d)=2^{\left(d-1\right)}\left(d-2\right)+2$. 1 digit numbers start at index 0, the 2 digit numbers begin at index 2, the 3 digit numbers at 6, 4 digit numbers at 18, etc.

The formula that gives the number of digits for a given index $n$ is $s$ inverted: $s^{-1}(n)=\left\lfloor\frac{W\left(\ln(2)\cdot\frac{n-2}2\right)}{\ln 2}\right\rfloor+2$, where $W$ is Lambert's W function. $s^{-1}(n)$ is the same as $d(n)$ mentioned earlier. (Note $d(n)$ is not a true inverse of $s(n)$ because it maps multiple input values to a single output value.)

Then $f(n)=s(d(n))$

Putting these together, the bit at index $n$ in $B$ is:
$$\begin{align}
\text{value of first d(n) digit number: }&a = 2^{d(n)-1} \\
\text{value of number that n points to: }&v =a + \left\lfloor\frac{n-f(n)}{d(n)}\right\rfloor\\
\text{index of bit to obtain: }&i = (n-f(n)) \bmod d(n)\\
\text{value of bit to obtain: }&b = \left\lfloor\frac{v}{2^{d(n)-i-1}}\right\rfloor \bmod 2\\
\end{align}$$

Using 500 as an example: $a=2^{7-1}=64, v = 64+\lfloor(178/7)\rfloor=89, i=178\bmod 7=3, b=\lfloor 89/2^{7-3-1}\rfloor \bmod 2=11\bmod 2=1$